# Color handlebars table row depnding on value

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How do i color a specific row in a table depending on the value in that row?

```
                {{#each files}}
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left">{{filename}}</td>
                    {{#if status === "Completed"}}
                    <td style="text-align:right color:green">{{status}}</td>
                    {{#else status === "Pending"}}
                    <td style="text-align:right color:yellow">{{status}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
```

I loop through a list of files and i want to color the status depending if the value is completed or the value is pending?

Comment: It sounds like you should conditionally add a CSS class to the row.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to make an equality helper if you aren't already using one:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper({
  eq: (v1, v2) => v1 === v2,
});
```

Then use it in the loop:

```
{{#each files}}
  <tr style="{{if (eq "Completed" status) "color:green"}} {{if (eq "Pending" status) "color:yellow"}}">
    <td>{{filename}}</td>
    <td>{{status}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```